# create route after change pptp vpn ip

Tags: vpn, route, pptp

I have a PPTP VPN running great BUT I want to change the ppp0 IP and when I do that I loose the route configuration.

Here is the routing table with everything working

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
xxx-xxx-xx-xxx. 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.1.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

and after change ppp0 IP I get this

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    303    0        0 wlan0
xxx-xxx-xx-xxx. 192.168.0.1     255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     303    0        0 wlan0
192.168.100.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

how do I get these 2 lines back?

```
192.168.1.1     *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
```

Thank you.